# HTML2FPDF - Positioning the writeHTML output

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf

I have the following code:

```
function convert($contents, $name){ 
  echo($link); //prints nothing
  $pdf=new HTML2FPDF();
  $pdf->AddPage();
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
  $pdf->Cell(40,10, "Entry Report");
  $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 12);
  $pdf->Cell(100,10, $_SESSION['currdate']);
  $pdf->WriteHTML( $contents );
  $pdf->Output($name, "D");
}
```

By default the writeHTML content is positioned within the PDF at the top...How do I offset the wrriten content that is placed in the pdf by the writeHTML function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [FPDF](http://fpdf.org) you can use [SetX()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/setx.htm), [SetY()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/sety.htm) or [SetXY()](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/setxy.htm).